# Sitecore Item Web API - Template item not found error

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

I am trying to create a item via Item Web Api and I am not being able to figure out what is wrong with my call.

The template ID does exist as well as the parent ID.

POST:

```
POST /-/item/v1/?name=Foo&template=%23%7b57ABCEB7-25E5-4F73-88D8-9E66E79EA87C%7d%23&sc_database=master&payload=Content&fields=DataTest&sc_itemid=%23%7b110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9%7d%23 HTTP/1.1
X-Scitemwebapi-Username: sitecore\admin
X-Scitemwebapi-Password: b
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: sandbox
Content-Length: 14
Expect: 100-continue
Proxy-Connection: Close

DataTest=Value
```

RESPONSE:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 19 Mar 2014 00:25:34 GMT
Content-Length: 65

{"statusCode":500,"error":{"message":"Template item not found."}}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you try removing the `%23` (#) from the `template` and `sc_item` parameters? Failing that, try using the relative template path and see if that works

Comment: Perfect, I didn`t notice this extra sign. Post as an answer so I can mark as answred the question. Tks

Answer (score 0):

There are some extra encoded characters in the request URL, your `template` and `sc_itemid` parameters are wrapped in %23 (#) characters.

> POST
>   /-/item/v1/?name=Foo&template=%23%7b57ABCEB7-25E5-4F73-88D8-9E66E79EA87C%7d%23&sc_database=master&payload=Content&fields=DataTest&sc_itemid=%23%7b110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9%7d%23
>   HTTP/1.1

Check your code to make sure how they got there but removing them should fix the issue.